# Question about the Osgood Box

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of episode 8 of Doctor Who Series 9,

> The Doctor finally convices Bonnie (Zygon Clara) that the Osgood Boxes don't actually do anything, and they only exist to mantain the Ceasefire.

However, Kate points out that since they already know that,

> the boxes are pointless, and The Doctor answers "Yeah, you said that the other fifteen times" and proceeds to erase Kate's memory of the event, but spares Zygon Clara's memory because she already got the point.

So my question is:

Was Bonnie the Zygon who tried to get to the Osgood Box the other fifteen times? Or were there 15 different "Rebel Zygons"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think the Doctor implied that there have been 15 other rebellions. He meant that they had done this final showdown over the boxes 15 times.

That is, in the standoff either Bonnie or Kate pressed the button before the Doctor was able to convince them not to, so he had to reset to the start of that scene.

This makes a lot more sense than presuming he meant the whole rebellion had happened 15 times before.

Comment: Oooohhh!! This makes more sense. Hadn't thought about that.

Comment: Me either. It makes a lot more sense than there possibly having been 15 other rebellions.

Answer (score 3):

I thought about the same issue, and my conclusion was:

### the Doctor was lying.

If there had been fifteen previous Zygon rebellions of sufficient scale to lead to a confrontation in the Black Archive with the Osgood box, *someone* would have remembered. There would have been traces in public records, for goodness sake!

And since Bonnie's end role was to take over as the second Osgood, that doesn't fit well with the same having happened fifteen times before. What would have happened to the previous Bonnies? The Doctor would have kept their memories intact for the same reason he did this Bonnie - so they'd learn from their mistakes.

---

An alternative theory is that **the previous Bonnies became some of the most anti-war Zygons**, e.g. the two in the form of little girls who were killed during *The Zygon Invasion* episode. This would also make sense, since anyone who'd been in Bonnie's position and persuaded so eloquently by the Doctor to stand down would see themselves as having a duty to uphold the peace afterwards, as Bonnie does in the end.

---

Yet another theory is that **the previous Bonnies had to be killed**. A possible scenario is that the last fifteen times, the humans didn't have the advantage of Clara getting inside the head of the Zygon rebel leader, so one of the buttons *actually got pressed*, leading to Kate's discovery that the boxes were empty and her subsequent memory-wipe.

Comment: Damn...I forgot Rule #1. Good answer!!

Comment: I just interpreted that as the Doctor joking, honestly.

Comment: Actually, now I'm more confused than ever. If there had never been a rebellion before, why would the Zygon rebels' motto be the same one that the Doctor had put in the boxes? But if there had been one (let alone 15!), how could UNIT not know about it? It's not as if all of UNIT's soldiers were in the memory-wiping room. Not to mention records, videos (like the one Bonnie made), other people's memories, etc. Besides, 15 separate splinter groups in about a year? That does not sound like a stable situation to me. Surely the Doctor would find a different planet in that case.